# Changing XYZ order when converting Euler-angles to quaternions

Tags: math, geometry, quaternions, euler-angles

I'm using the following code to produce a quaternion from XYZ Euler-Angles in radians:

```
c1 = Math.cos( x / 2 )
c2 = Math.cos( y / 2 )
c3 = Math.cos( z / 2 )

s1 = Math.sin( x / 2 )
s2 = Math.sin( y / 2 )
s3 = Math.sin( z / 2 )

quaternion = [
              c1 * c2 * c3 - s1 * s2 * s3,
              s1 * c2 * c3 + c1 * s2 * s3,
              c1 * s2 * c3 - s1 * c2 * s3,
              c1 * c2 * s3 + s1 * s2 * c3,
             ]
```

from:
http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToQuaternion/index.htm

This produces a quaternion that first rotates around the z, then y, then finally the x-axis - Z-Y-X. Is it possible to alter this formula so that it rotates around the axes in a different order? What I'm looking for is the opposite, so X-Y-Z.

Comment: You can create 3 quaternions for rotations around single axis, and compose them by multiplication any way you need.

Comment: Yeah that's definitely the most versatile way and is how i'm working atm. Just looking for a more preferment method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone's interested...

Yes you can, turns out on this occasion I just needed to swap the plus and minus signs around to get an X-Y-Z order (traditionally written ZYX). 
Like so...

```
       [
        c1 * c2 * c3 + s1 * s2 * s3,
        s1 * c2 * c3 - c1 * s2 * s3,
        c1 * s2 * c3 + s1 * c2 * s3,
        c1 * c2 * s3 - s1 * s2 * c3
        ]
```

Three.js has a full list of the different formulas for various xyz orders - in the function THREE.Quaternion.setFromEuler

https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/eulerToQuaternion/steps/index.htm